# firewalld zones and ICMP Packets

Tags: firewalld, icmp

How are the zones in [`firewalld`](http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora19/man1/firewalld.1.html) configured with respect to ICMP packets? Do they act differently for interfaces and sources?

**1. How firewalld filter ICMP packets?**

I would assume the main zones act as they are named,

```
drop : DROP
block : REJECT
trust : ACCEPT
```

but how about the other zones? `public`, `external`, `work`, `internal`, `home`? Do they by default accept or reject ICMP packets?

**2. Does this functionality differ depending on whether the zone is assigned by an interface vs by a source?**

For instance, would there be a difference in terms of the source IP:`172.28.0.2` in these two settings?

```
some-zone 
  interfaces: eno1
  sources: 
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

vs

```
some-zone 
  interfaces: 
  sources: 172.28.0.0/16
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**1. How does firewalld handle ICMP packets in the various zones?**

From Red Hat's firewalld documentation, specifically this section, titled: [5.15. Configuring Complex Firewall Rules with the "Rich Language" Syntax](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/configuring_complex_firewall_rules_with_the_rich-language_syntax#Understanding_the_Rich_Rule_Command_Options):

> icmp-block uses the action **reject** internally

(my emphasis, to point out that "drop" and "accept" are not used). The default zones do not appear to block any ICMP types -- see the XML files in /usr/lib/firewalld/zones and the lack of `<icmp-block>` entries.

To see the current state of any zone-based icmp blocks, run: `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones` and look for the `icmp-blocks:` entry.

**2. Does this functionality differ depending on whether the zone is assigned by an interface vs by a source?**

Not directly. `interfaces` and `sources` tell firewalld to select the corresponding zone, which will then have (some or none) icmp-blocks that will apply. See: http://www.firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html which talks about it:

> Binding an interface to a zone means that this zone settings are used to restrict traffic via the interface.

and

> Binding a source to a zone means that this zone settings will be used to restrict traffic from this source.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -i icmp /lib/firewalld/zones/*.xml
$ rpm -q firewalld
firewalld-0.4.4.1-1.fc24.noarch
```

so it will be handled by the default target for the zone.  Note that `man firewall.zone` tells us zones without an explicit default will reject packets.

It should also be [clear in the GUI](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Security_Guide/sec-Configuring_the_Firewall.html).